# join two tables(one of them is part of the other)

Tags: mysql, join

I have two tables Table_A and Table_B and i want to join those tables to optain Table_c as the result:

Table_A:

```
+-----------+-----------+---------+
| tableA_id | tableB_id | v_id    |
+-----------+-----------+---------+
| 1         | 2         | 27      |
| 2         | 3         | 27      |
| 3         | 3         | 28      |
| 4         | 1         | 26      |
| 5         | 2         | 26      |
| 6         | 3         | 26      |
| 7         | 1         | 24      |
| 8         | 1         | 25      |
+-----------+-----------+---------+
```

Table_B:

```
+-----------+-----------+
| tableB_id | s_name    | 
+-----------+-----------+
| 1         | s1        |
| 2         | s2        | 
| 3         | s3        | 
+-----------+-----------+
```

Table_c:

```
+-----------+-----------+-----------++--------+
| tableB_id | s_name    | tableA_id | v_id    |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------+
| 1         | s1        | null      | null    |
| 2         | s2        | 1         | 27      | 
| 3         | s3        | 2         | 27      |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------+
```

I tried different queries, but i couldn't reach the desired output.
This is MYSQL query:  *Edit: reverse table order.

```
SELECT s.tableB_id, s.s_name, v.tableA_id, v.v_id
FROM Table_B  as s 
left OUTER JOIN Table_A  as v
ON v.v_id=27
```

**EDIT:**
The result should be all Table_B data on left and assign to it table_A data if any or make it null. How can i make this?

**Last Edit:**
Here is a solution i came up with:

```
SELECT s.tableB_id , s.s_name, v.tableA_id, v.v_id
FROM Table_B s , Table_A v
WHERE v.v_id=27 AND v.tableB_id = s.tableB_id 

UNION

SeLECT s.tableB_id , s.s_name, null as tableA_id, null as v_id
FROM Table_B s
WHERE s.tableB_id NOT IN (SELECT s.tableB_id 
FROM Table_B s , Table_A v
WHERE v.v_id=27 AND v.tableB_id = s.tableB_id )
```

Comment: Hint: This is your where clause `ON v.v_id=27`. You should be joining on the common column(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
SELECT tb.tableB_id, tb.s_name, ta.tableA_id, ta.v_id
FROM Table_B tb LEFT JOIN Table_A ta
  ON tb.tableB_id = ta.tableB_id
```

To choose only one you could use:

```
SELECT tb.tableB_id, tb.s_name, ta.tableA_id, ta.v_id
FROM Table_B tb LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM Table_A 
 WHERE v_id = 27) ta
  ON tb.tableB_id = ta.tableB_id
```

Comment: This gives me Table_B data which is associated with v_id=27 only (2 rows), but i want all Table_B data at the right side.

Comment: I tried it now and it works. Thanks :) i also found a solution (last edit in my question) but i think yours is more obvious.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT distinct s.tableB_id, s.s_name, v.tableA_id, v.v_id
 FROM Table_A as v 
 left OUTER JOIN Table_B as s
 ON v.tableB_id =s.tableB_id and v.v_id = 27;
```

Answer (score 0):

use this query hope fully you will get result

```
SELECT s.tableB_id, s.s_name, v.tableA_id, v.v_id
FROM Table_A as v 
left OUTER JOIN Table_B as s ON s.tableB_id=v.tableB_id
WHERE v.v_id=27
```

Answer (score 0):

Reverse the order, making it `b LEFT JOIN a` and add the condition for the common column (`tableB_id`):

```
SELECT s.tableB_id, s.s_name, v.tableA_id, v.v_id
FROM Table_B as s
  LEFT OUTER JOIN Table_A as v 
    ON  v.tableB_id = s.tableB_id
    AND v.v_id=27 ;
```